# Access nested objects and arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with the Mailgun API. I have a variable with some objects and arrays inside that looks like this:

```
$result =
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'http_response_body' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'items' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'geolocation' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'country' => 'UK',
           'region' => '72',
           'city' => 'London',
        )),
         'tags' => 
        array (
        ),
         'mailing-list' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'list-id' => 'email@address.com',
           'address' => 'email@address.com',
           'sid' => '123456',
        )),
         'ip' => '123.456.789',
         'log-level' => 'info',
         'id' => 'ABCA',
         'campaigns' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          stdClass::__set_state(array(
             'name' => 'TEST',
             'id' => 'test123',
          )),
        ),
      )),
    ),
   'http_response_code' => 200,
));
?>
```

I need to access every single information inside (e.g. the IP, the country, the region), . I tried multiple solutions, including using a `foreach`.

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row->items->ip;
}
```

However I keep getting

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I know I am not accessing the data the right way. Could you advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you mean to be looping over `$result->http_response_body->items`. What you are actually doing is looping over `$result->items` which doesn't seem to exist.

```
foreach($result->http_response_body->items as $item) {
    echo $item->ip;
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you. I completely ignored the "http_response_body" part.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. In the future try to make your data clearer. Maybe even just showing it as arrays would be easier to look at.